# Defining a ring homomorphism in proving $|C| \cdot \frac{\chi(C)}{\dim V} $

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> **Lemma** irreducible representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$, $C$ conjugacy class, then
> $$|C| \cdot \frac{\chi(C)}{\dim V} $$
> is an algebraic integer.

In the start of this proof we have:

> Define a ring homomorphism
>
> $$ \varphi:\mathbb{C}[G] \longrightarrow Hom (V,V)$$
> $$ g \mapsto \rho(g)$$
> $$\sum \alpha_g g \longrightarrow \sum \alpha_g \rho(g) $$

How do we know it is a ring homomorphism. I can see some sort of multiplication will be one operation but what is the other?

Then the proof proceeds by

> (this $\varphi$) induces
> $$\mathbb{C}[G]^G \longrightarrow Hom(V,V)^G $$
> which is equivalent to
> $$\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{C}[G]) \longrightarrow Hom_G(V,V)$$

I cannot see how $\mathbb{C}[G]^G =\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{C}[G])$ holds. Ive tried
$$h \cdot \sum_{g \in G}\alpha_g g=\sum_g \alpha(h\cdot g) $$ but cannot see how this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see some sort of multiplication will be one operation but what is the other?

Rings have two operations: multiplication and addition.

> I cannot see how $Z(\Bbb C[G])=\Bbb C[G]^G$ holds.

To be central in $\Bbb C[G]$ it's enough to commute with every $g\in G$. Commuting with $g$ is the same as being a fixed point under conjugation by $g$.

Comment: How do we know that the action is conjugation?

Comment: @sandstone If you didn't know what the action of $G$ on $\Bbb C[G]$ is then that is one of the *very first* things you should have been asking about! Go back into whatever you're reading to verify this.